# Реализация сортировки выборки из бд

Tags: выборка, сортировка, запрос, php, mysql

Как реализовать сортировку и выборку фильтрами в одном запросе?

Т.е. есть таблица с данными и форма с несколькими input'ами для фильтрации результатов. Необходимо сделать так, что бы пользователь мог сортировать эту фильтрованную выборку по нужным ему столбцам таблицы.

Картинка для наглядности:
[image: Картинка для наглядности]

Answer (score 2):

Обычно делается на javascript. Ну и готовых решений тоже хватает. Вот например http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/.